# Laravel 8 with xampp

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm having error after clicking register button.

[image]

Register Controller

[image]

Blade View

[image]

@csrf is added below my post method. Any help or solutions will be helpful.

Comment: Setup up with Laravel Breeze for simple Auth method.

Comment: Even better, if you share your code.

Comment: @MeherUllahKhanRaj, I have share the code. Please assist

Comment: @MeherUllahKhanRaj, is bcoz I'm running on camp with latest version? Tried on the above link provided. No effect 

Answer (score 0):

Try alternative

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">`
Save

Comment: Tried didn't really worked.

Answer (score 0):

under the form tag try this one:
@csrf

Comment: Yeap. Its added

Comment: Please remove the input tag holding value {{csrf_token}}